# Facebook app doesn't resize

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I have the problem that my facebook app page doesn't resize the height. I know there are a lot of questions from people that have similar problems. But I've tried setting FB.Canvas.setSize(), FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow() and a function that "should" resize the canvas page each 2 seconds and nothing works.

**EDIT**

I now tried it with a minimal code that ***should*** work (as fas as I understand it) but it don't.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">body { overflow: hidden; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    cookie: true
                });
            };
            window.onload = function() {
                FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(100);
            }
        </script>
        <div style="height: 1000px; width: 20px; background-color: #006;"></div>
        <div>End</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of the app settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this issue and this are the changes I mage:

- Removing the script tag that loads the facebook lib.
- Adding the JS code to load the facebook lib.
- Moving this code right below the starting body tag.

I don't know whether all of those steps are necessary.

Here is the code that works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">body { overflow: hidden; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId: "xxxxxxx",
                    status : true,
                    cookie: true
                });
                FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
            };

            (function(d, debug){
                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
                ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
            }(document, /*debug*/ true));
        </script>
        <!-- page content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need both resize functions. Simply call `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()` at some point after your `FB.init()` call.

Comment: Yes, of course I tried this first, but it didn't work. Then I added the setSize() function but this also didn't work, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

If you site doesn't need to resize more than once, you should only use the FB.Canvas.SetSize(), to save CPU-Power ;)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, sure. But also a single SetSize() doesn't work. And I can't say whether the app page will change its height or not.

Comment: Then you should only use SetAutoGrow(), it will keep reading the page to check if changes size ..

Comment: That was my first try, of course. I edited my question to make it clear.

Comment: Just took a look at your codes, i can't seem to find your javascript setAutoGrow anywhere in them ?

Comment: It is in line 399 of the source code. If you load the page outside of the facebook iframe another page will be shown. Maybe thats the reason why you didn't see it.

Comment: In line 399 is `<li class="divider">&middot;</li>`code..
The only thing with relation to the FB javascript is
`<!-- FB Like Button Script -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>` in line 436

Comment: Hello Rasmus. Thank you for trying to help me. When you open the link in my question: Do you see a page with some penguins and a German text about the red hot chili peppers? The source code you are looking at is returned by a different request then that, facebook makes to load the page into the iFrame. You can search the source code for "pepper" or "Hamburg" or any other text part visible in the Faceboo app iFrame. You won't find any of them, because it is a different page. And so you cannot find the javascript I am talking about.

Comment: But if you don't see any penguins at the Facebook page, please tell me. Then I have another error.

Comment: When you open the Link above in Firefox and make a right click into the iFrame, then select This Frame > View Frame Source, you should see the real source code of the page you are seeing. I think so ... I have some firefox plugins installed, so maybe it behaves different at your system.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the problem that AutoGrow does exactly what it says on the tin. It grows the page (hint: it doesn't shrink it). What we ended up going with was:

```
FB.init({
    appId : 'appid',
    status : true,
    cookie : true
});
FB.Canvas.setSize({height:600});
setTimeout("FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()",500);
```